# Proper way to expose an API c++

Tags: c++, api-design

I'm developing an API for my project and I would like to use this API on future projects. The problem is how I expose it:

The API uses a lot of libraries and I don't want the client code to download and compile these libraries over and over again. So my solution is to do something like this:

Engine.hpp

```
class __declspec(dllexport) Engine
    {
    public:
        Engine();

        ~Engine();
    public:
        void run_window();

        // std::vector<UI::Window*> window_list;
    };

    std::string __declspec(dllexport) get_version();
```

Right now this work as it is, but I want to add some other classes I've created to this exposed class, but the problem arises when I try to include my class, which is dependent on a class (in this case, GLFW). The class simply looks like this:

Window.hpp

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

class Window{
public:
   Window(std::string name);
   ...
private:
   GLFWwindow* m_window;
};
```

So attempting to use UI::Window naturally causes a pre-compilation error saying it can't find GLFW header files, which is not included in client code's cmake. As far as I'm concerned the functions of libraries in Engine should be compiled alongside my code and should be included in the .dll and .lib files, but I'm getting this include error as expected.

I'm a bit new to API design so is there a way / best practice to expose my library dependent code to the client without having them import every single library?

I can use static variables inside the cpp files of Engine but I want the variables to be class members and I want the client to access some of them.

Comment: Multiple different approaches are used, typically, in these situations: pimpl idioms, factories with virtual implementations, etc... There is no single C++ authority of some kind that sits on a throne and deems one or the other to be the "proper" or The Official Way. As such, any answers here would be merely opinion, and inappropriate. Just keep reading your textbook and learning C++, and you'll eventually understand all possible approaches and pick the best one for you.

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport)` is wrong. You should define a macro that expands to `__declspec(dllexport)` in your project, but to `__declspec(dllimport)` when used by a client: `class MY_API Engine...`

Comment: You don't need to include the header if all you  need is a pointer to some type it defines. That's what forward declarations are for.

Comment: `__declspec(dllexport)` is msvc specific. Macro is required to handle this on all compilers. CMake has a feature to address this issue: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html

Comment: First make sure you're design properly splits UI from Engine by defining interfaces between the two (abstract baseclasses). And this means **remove ALL your static/global variables** from your design. This by the way also makes your Engine unit testable which will be a great bonus in a big project, so you might want to read up on unit testability and dependency injection.

Comment: @zdf I already use a macro like that just wanted to make my code shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're `#include`ing Window.hpp in your compilation unit, and Window.hpp contains `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>`, so that's what the compiler tries to do.  It has no idea *why* you're including glfw3.h, just that you told it to do so and that it can't find that file.

Luckily, you don't actually *need* glfw3.h.  Since `Window` only contains a *pointer* to a `GLFWwindow` it has no need for the full definition of `GLFWwindow` in its header; it just needs to know that it's a class that exists.  You tell it that using a forward-declaration:

```
class GLFWwindow;

class Window{
public:
   Window(std::string name);
   ...
private:
   GLFWwindow* m_window;
};
```

Then in Window.cpp you can `#include` the full glfw3.h header so that the `Window` member functions defined there know what to do.  That's fine though, since Window.cpp doesn't need to be compiled when compiling your program (only when compiling your library).

You will still need to link your program to the glfw libraries though.